# GET via Ajax, exists but undefined

Tags: php, ajax, post, get, undefined

I'm struggling so hard with a very silly bug. I send a form via Ajax with POST but since I also wanted a GET variable, I put it in the url.

I have something like:

```
var xhr = getXHR();
var id = <?php echo $id ?>;
var xhrUrl = 'request_performupdate?id='+id;
```

Then, in the `performupdate` function I have :

```
if($_GET)
{
    $a = fopen('get.txt','w');
    $test=$_GET['id'];
    fwrite($a,'idlol:'.$test);
}

$id=$test;
```

But here, the file `get.txt` is well written with the correct value, but I get a notice error saying `$test` (the second one) doesn't exist... That's unbelievable ! Hope you will have an idea, thanks very much.

Comment: i notice `request_performupdate` does not have `.php` in the ending.

Comment: It is normal. It is a function called via a route file and a controller.